# dead kernel after importing pybel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to

```
import pybel
```

in jupyter-notebook and it says

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

When I use it in python3, I get:

```
Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2018, 09:53:17) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybel
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
    what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing using `pip3` instead of `conda`

```
pip3 install pybel
```

works